# Get master request in Symfony 2.4

Tags: php, symfony, request

When rendering another controller from the view, master request gets lost - this means that, for example, GET parameters will not be available in that rendered (included) controller.

What is the way to access the query string in rendered controllers, except accessing $_GET directly (this works).

I've found some legacy code in the project which does the thing, but it's deprecated in 2.4 and will be removed in 3.0 already:

```
$this->container->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest();
```

Here $this->container is the ContainerInterface.

Comment: Have you read this: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RequestStack.html

From the `RequestStack` you can get the master request `$stack->getMasterRequest()`.

The request as a service is deprecated `$this->container->get('request')`, but this stack replaced it.